# Passing Arguments to Event Handlers

Tags: reactjs

I'd be grateful if you could help me with my problem.
I've written a component to demonstrate the information of an array which includes both index.js and TableData.js files.Transferring the information of array from index.js to TableData in order to demonstrating them. 
I **passed the arguments to event handler** correctly but I get an error. What's the problem with my code? In which part have I made a mistake?
[image]

App.js

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {TableData} from './Layouts'


class App extends Component {
    state = {
        productList: [
            {id: 11, name: 'CD', price: '2000', describe: 'Educational'},
            {id: 24, name: 'Pen', price: '3500', describe: 'Design'},
            {id: 83, name: 'Pencil', price: '2500', describe: 'Design'}
        ],
    };

    handleDeleteByIndex = index => {
        const product = this.state.productList;
        product.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({productList: product});
    };


    render() {
        const {productList} = this.state;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <TableData rows={productList} onDeleteRow={this.handleDeleteByIndex}/>

            </Fragment>
        );

    }
}

export default App
```

TableData.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TableHead,
    TableRow,
    Paper
} from '@material-ui/core';


//****** Style CSS ******
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        overflowX: 'auto'
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 650
    }
});

const test = 'right';

const TableData= (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Name Product</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Price</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Describe</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {props.rows.map((item, index) => (
                        <TableRow key={item.id}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {item.name}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align={test} data={item.name}>{item.price}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{item.describe}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">
                                <button onClick={() => props.handleDeleteByIndex(index)}>
                                    DEL
                                </button>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    );
};

export default TableData
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling a function that does not exist. The passed down function in props is called `onDeleteRow`, not `handleDeleteByIndex`.

Just change it into:

```
onClick={() => props.onDeleteRow(index)}
```